# How to add tagline above form?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add a tagline above the form. I am not able to identify where I should add the line. I need a clean line on top of my form.
So far, I have simply added a `<h2>` inside the form. Look pathetic

Here's the [site](http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/).

This is what I have done so far

```
<h2 align='left'>Get your course details</h2>
```

I need to make it properly align with the form.

Comment: Please add the releavant code to your post here instead of just linking your page.

Comment: use css to style it as you would like? there is no automatically styled tagline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want like this:
     This is using only hr tag in html.

[image]

Comment: I liked it! I have implemented the same.